# nameof() operator for property of generic class

Tags: c#, generics, c#-6.0, nameof

I often use the C# 6.0 `nameof(...)` operator in tests to determine, if e.g. the `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged` is called for the right property. Sometimes I have a generic class implementing the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface:

```cs
public ViewModel<T>:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
     public string Name { get; set; }

     public T Value { get; set; }
}
```

To get the name of the property `Name` by now I use a arbitrary type to get the name: `nameof(ViewModel<string>.Name)`. This solution is possible but might result in problems, if the generic type parameter gets constrainted.

Is there a possibility to get the name without a specific generic type? I suggested something like `nameof(ViewModel<T>.Name)` or `nameof(ViewModel<>.Name)`, but that doesn't work.

Comment: I closed the question as a duplicate because I think the answer is "no, it is not possible", and the other question explains why/how. This could be useful, of course.